# firefox not trigger default handler

Tags: firefox, click, stoppropagation

The problem is, why firefox (3-10) do not calls default link handler, when I`m using stop propagation and clicking link with Ctrl key? All other browsers, even including IE!, do that.

Code sample:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Click me</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Just open firefox, hold down Ctrl key and click link. Nothing happens, why?

Answer (score 1):

Because the "Ctrl+click" behavior is implemented in an event handler that Firefox attaches to the window (the actual setup is a bit more complicated, but that's what it looks like from the point of view of the web page) and you're preventing propagation of the event to that handler, so it never fires.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bug, reported to bugzilla:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=748740

You can vote for it :)